# Is there a jQuery equivalent to Ruby’s Object#tap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

Does jQuery have an equivalent to [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap)?

Let’s say I want to do something like this:

```
foo.append($("<nav>").tap(function (nav) {
  $.each(urls, function (url) {
    nav.append("<a>").attr(url).text(url)
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like to do that can't be accomplished with basic chaining?

Comment: How is `Object#tap` different from `$.fn.each` ?

Comment: @MichaelMior OK, I added an example. But I think Raynos just answered my question. :-)

Comment: @Raynos Haha, there is no difference. I’m stupid. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called `.each`

`nodes.each(inspect).map(mapper).each(inspect).etc()`

Comment: This isn't quite `.tap`.  I should be able to `tap` an array object, and get the whole array to act upon